# Was flagging as "Rude or Offensive" the wrong choice here?

Tags: support, flagging

I flagged a comment by the OP of [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/250418/programming-first-bot-application) (now deleted) as "rude or offensive".

I don't have access to the comment any more (and don't know if it was eventually removed), but for the <10K+ users it basically was OP's rant about the response the question got (a link to [Where to Start?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start)) and how asking a bunch of "computer nerds" was a waste of his/her time and how he/she shouldn't have expected a "socially acceptable response" from the users here. I was moderately surprised when I checked back and found the flag was declined.

Now, I personally don't think that this was overly rude; I just felt it crossed the line of respectable behavior and could be reasonably construed as rude by another user. Now that I think about it, "rude or offensive" could be a bit of a stretch, as this is probably pretty mild compared to some other stuff people have left...

I'm not particularly worried about the declined flag itself; I would just like to know where I went wrong so I can avoid making the same mistake again.

Would flagging as "Not constructive" have been a better choice? Should I be saving "Rude or offensive" for the more vile comments some users might leave?

Comment: Don't worry to much about it. The large majority of flags are handled by the moderators. Only flagging for spam triggers an automated response.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Your comment made me realize that I forgot to include my actual question in my question. Oops... Edited, hopefully makes more sense now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fat fingered this.

The conversation in the comments had definitely taken a non constructive turn, and your flag was helpful (~ it pointed me to the right direction). The type of the flag is secondary, and it didn't play a role here.

Apologies. I owe you a helpful flag ;)

Comment: No worries about the mistake; happens to the best of us. Thanks for the quick response! Just for future reference, though, is there ever a time where the distinction between "not constructive" and "rude or offensive" would be important? Or is just getting something bad flagged the overriding concern no matter the specific type?

Comment: @user3580294 With comment flags, the specific type of the flag doesn't really matter. Pick the one you think best describes what's going on (nc is broader than rude/offensive, it may be the safer choice between the two). With post flags, on the other hand, the type of the flag _sometimes_ matter, as it will enter the flag in one of our review queues (e.g. close flags -> close queue, very low quality flag -> low quality posts queue)

Comment: All right, that clears everything up, and the bit about post flags is a great addition. Thanks again!

Comment: @user3580294 if one more person (I've got the same declined flag) had flagged it, it would have been auto-deleted (see 'Who can delete comments' in http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756/213963 ).  There are also certain words that will cause the comment to be deleted with a single flag (as hinted at in http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99853/213963 ) - I'm moderately surprised that the comment didn't fall into that category.

Comment: I think this is why you are one of my favorite mods on SE.  I may not agree with you but you are rational and willing to admit when you make a mistake.