# Why too opinion based?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/310733/how-to-learn-and-be-productive-in-a-language-which-you-resent

According to [guidelines for subjectives questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) it

1. Clearly asks to explain how.
2. Constructive, given that all widely used languages have bad parts.
3. Invites to share experiences rather than opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This site is focused on questions that can be answered (preferably definitively), and not just discussed. This, I'm afraid, is not the case with your question.

We simply don't know you well enough to comment on how *you* can get over your resentment and be productive with the language in question (or anything, really). We don't even know if generic advice like "there probably is another language that's equally appropriate for the task at hand" is applicable in your situation.

I don't see a way to re-open this.

---

Further reading:

- [Why was my question closed or down voted?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted)
- [On discussions and why they don't make good questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6742/25936)
- [Green fields, blue skies, and the white board - what is too broad?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6961/25936)