# Is this the right place for a question about hosting e-commerce improvement

Tags: support, questions

I work as a developer (focused on design and frontend - some knowladge on backend / server) but I work alone providing full service for my clients. One of them has an e-commerce growing a lot! To a point where it's site went down due to high traffic. I want to learn more to decide what is the best hosting option for this case. I know the way to go is VPS but which one? 1gb? 2gb? linux, windows, ssd, connection, bandwidth, cpanel, no cpanel, etc .. So many questions .. What is the best place to clear my doubts?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Green fields, blue skies, and the white board - what is too broad?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6961/green-fields-blue-skies-and-the-white-board-what-is-too-broad)

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not the right place, because

- recommending 3rd party services is [off-topic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site.
- recommending specific software products or hardware is off-topic as well.

The only place in the SE network I am aware of where you can discuss such topics are the [chatrooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/). .

I would also recommend to have a look at  [Why was my question closed or down voted?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487)