# My question was moved to Software Recomendations, why was this?

Tags: discussion

My [question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17586/is-there-a-library-or-tutorial-in-creating-a-report-designer?noredirect=1#comment25467_17586) was moved to Software Recommendations.

As you can see, it clearly needs help from programmers as it asks for libraries or tutorials on the subject. And because of this, it was commented there which was:

> While asking for libraries is fully OK here at SR, we don't provide tutorials or the like. The scope of this site is to recommend specific software to your named requirements. To prevent your question from being "put down", I strongly recommend you edit it to meet this site's scope.

So either of the two moderators is right. I'm voting for the one at SoftRec. Why? You might ask, well I was asking for libraries, not built software for my purpose.

The software, "Jaspersoft" was just an example of what I want to output. I didn't ask "I needed a report generator like Jasper", what I asked are libraries or at least code examples.

I do hope that this would not be closed without my curiosity being satisfied. :)

Comment: SoftwareRecs is the **only** current SE site where recommendations are on-topic, and then **only** when they meet specific criteria (specifically: a purpose and some objective requirements). If you want recommendations for software (*including libraries*) and meet those criteria, the question belongs on SR. If you want recommendations for *anything else* (e.g. tutorials) the question *doesn't belong on SE*. *"how do I create the report designer"* is way too broad everywhere on SE.

Answer (score 6):

Only a moderator can migrate a question to any beta site. In fact the only two sites we can vote to migrate are Programmers Meta (this site) and Stack Overflow. Whichever moderator moved that question is the only person who can explain the "why" behind the move.

I think that is a problematic question *as written* for both sites. If I had more time today when you asked it I would have tried to help improve it, but I was unclear about your intent and had other work to do at that time. By the time I came back around to check it out, it was already migrated.

- It is written *almost* like a product request, as if you are looking for a library you can leverage and extend. If you are looking for a piece of software, SR.SE would be the appropriate site. In fact the title reads that way: "is there a library or tutorial..."
- While it does ask for advice about how to code something in a report, that is [too broad](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6490/22815) for Programmers.SE. The title also sounds like a [resource request](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6487/22815) which is off-topic.

I think you should ask the question here on Programmers after editing it to be clear that it is not a product recommendation. Do not simply say "I am not looking for a recommendation" but change the wording and tone of the question. Next, make it laser-focused. You will likely need to experiment with your code and figure out what works and does not work. Simply asking [where to start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6366/22815) will not end well, either.

You can always drop into [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard) for help wording your question, or open another meta question here if you have more specific concerns about how to ask your question.

The only remaining housekeeping is whether to edit the question on SR.SE and migrate it back, or self-delete that question and ask here again. I would lean toward deleting and asking over simply because the logistics may be easier, but others may prefer to migrate it back.

Comment: Well said.  I wish I could put a bounty on a meta answer.