# Would questions concerning how a segment of code would likely be written in another language in topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

Let's say I know Haskell and I'm learning Scala? Could I ask "I'm trying to accomplish X in Scala, I couldn't get it working.  Here is the Scala I wrote that either I don't think is idiomatic, or isn't working, or is incomplete because I'm missing information Y. But here is how I would write it in Haskell. What is the idiomatic approach to this problem in Scala?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that sort of question would not be on-topic here.  It *might* be on-topic at StackOverflow, but you need to make sure that you come up with a [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct, Example)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions) for your question.

Comment: doesn't look like good fit for SO either: [Is “How do I convert code from this languange to this language” too broad?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296119/839601) ---> [excellent explanation in a dupe target over there](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265834/839601)

Answer (score 4):

No. This site is about *software development concepts* – think software architecture and design. We are not a code translation service. We do not cover implementation issues. We do not discuss best practices.

If you frame that questions about how a language-agnostic concept (e.g. type inference, or monads) manifests itself differently in Haskell and Scala, that might be on topic. But it also might be closed as *opinion-based*, because it could be misunderstood as asking which language is better. You would also have to take care to keep the question clear and answerable (real questions have answers!), rather than trying to start a discussion.

This can be difficult, so it might be worth looking into [our chatroom The Whiteboard](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard). There, you can get feedback on potential questions. But it's also a place for softer questions that do not fit within the scope of the main site.

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking is covered by this related meta question: [where to start?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6366/22815) which explains why your question would be off-topic here.

You may get useful feedback from [The Whiteboard](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard) if any of our resident FP experts are in chat.

Comment: Not really.  If I such a question is posted according to guidelines, I would post working Haskell code, and non-working Scala code that I've 'tried', or psuedocode, pointing out I couldn't find the necessary language features to implement a good solution in the language docs.  This is neither broad, nor vague, and it includes something I've tried.  I'm also not asking 'where to start', because I've already started by reading the docs, searching Google, and trying to write something.

Comment: Edited the comment to better reflect what my question would look like.