# Are questions regarding to Software performance testing off-topic?

Tags: support, on-topic-definition

I have been asked to prepare the whole performance test plan for the current project I'm working on. This is the first time I have to take forward such task by my own and ,honestly, I don't even know where to start by.

I would like to know if such subject is off-topic in SE.

I know asking for tools, guides, resources is off-topic and I'm afraid my question might cause that sort of answers. I'm not so interested on the tooling as I'm on the understanding the steps to follow, and the sort of test I should run on my system.

An overview or roadmap that could use as starting point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The topic of software performance testing is on-topic - it's part of "quality assurance and testing". However, please consult our guidance on [questions about where to start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start) to avoid your question being unclear or too broad. You should do some initial research on your own, and then come back with one or more specific questions or concerns.

Comment: This is what I'm doing now (and for the next days). Reading about theory and resources. I have made this question just to assure that, in the case of necessity I could ask here :-). Thank for the link "questions about here to start". I will read immediately