# Why the question got deleted?

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions

I have a question about my Software Engineering Stack Exchange post: [OAuth2 separate Authorization Validation Server trust](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/390711/oauth2-separate-authorization-validation-server-trust)

> [image]

Why the question got deleted? And why no reason was specified/can be seen.

Comment: It was Too Broad.  Sorry, I missed the close vote there.  I have applied the appropriate close reason to the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Green fields, blue skies, and the white board - what is too broad?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6961/green-fields-blue-skies-and-the-white-board-what-is-too-broad)

Comment: @RobertHarvey, it is not too broad. You are being subjective. I asked specific question - on best method of mutual app authorization in Public Cloud environment: "what would be the best way to allow only Authorization Server to connect/use Resource Server". There are only few possible alternatives - thus it can't be broad by the definition.

Comment: Try asking the question again without using the word "best" or any of its variations like best practice, most popular, etc.

Comment: Also, show your prior research.  What have you tried so far, and why didn't it work out for you?

Comment: I didn't try anything so far. All my prior research is asking question on Stackexchange. I don't see a reason in this website, if it is addressing only previously researched questions. If I do research, I will answer my question myself.

Comment: If by "research" you mean googling - there is nothing on the subject on Google. I tried that. But that's not "research".

Comment: Also talking about Software Engineering (and its subset - Software Architecture) - I don't believe that term "broad" is applicable at all. Architecture is by definition abstract subject (it does not depend on the specific implementation, but depends on interfaces). I am not sure how this reasoning is possible.

Comment: There's no way to answer a "what is the best way" question.  You haven't told us what you want, other than to use the word "best," which is unanswerable without a criteria to determine what "best" means to you.

Comment: I'm not an expert on OAuth, but isn't the whole point of OAuth to simplify this process?  Maybe you just need to learn more about OAuth.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I know that you are not an expert in OAuth2, this is visible because you did not understand the question and deleted it. Secondly - doesn't the fact that a person is implementing OAuth2 solution give you a hint that this person is having some background knowledge on this subject?

Comment: Simply stated: if you're merely looking for some free consultation, you're probably looking in the wrong place.

Comment: And judging from the two downvotes you got on that question, I'm not the only one that feels this way.

Comment: Free consultation? I am working on Open Source project. This is ridiculous.

Comment: So instead of arguing with me about what "too broad" means, do as I asked and focus your question more specifically so that it is answerable.

Comment: It is fully answerable, if it wouldn't have been deleted. The answers can be: - Use Client Authentication (now I checked that it's impossible - Heroku doesn't support it), Use "another method ideal in this situation" (which I don't know) - and a link to it. That's it. As simple as that.

Comment: Alternatively it can be answered: "There is no such way as of now existing" - and I will do RnD and share the new protocol with public. But I needed input from community, which I failed to receive here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I think you simply missed word "only" (it was initially in the text and still is). Admit it. This would make sense if word "only" is omitted from the question. If this is the case - you can just restore my question (undelete it).

Comment: Also why are you putting "status completed" tag? This request is not complete at all. I want to make it straight - you are getting revenue by exposing your reputation as a Stackexchange moderator/assosiate - this potentially can give you monetary revenue when finding jobs etc. Therefore I as a user (consumer) of this website have right to request you to close this ticket only when I confirm it is closed. This is not a pure volunteering, you have to be responsible on your actions.

Comment: amon correctly summarized things with: "But the mistake was just deleting before closing. A procedural error. Robert was not wrong to close or delete the question."  I would have put a binding close vote on the question as well.  Too broad as originally written and even with the edit. Not a good fit for the site; very little value for future visitors.

Comment: It is not to broad. Objectively. You are just covering your fellow administrator. It is absolutely specific question about Architecture and API security.

Comment: @GlenH7 I am still waiting for the question to be undeleted. It conforms to the site rules. Please keep your subjective prejustice to yourself. I am and will argument my point of view and will not change it just because somebody does not want to understand it.

Comment: @AntonPryamostanova multiple community members have explained to you why the question is not a good fit for the site.

Answer (score 7):

Thank you for pointing out that the question was deleted without a visible reason. Usually, questions are first closed with a reason before they are deleted. In the meanwhile, this has been rectified.

Robert Harvey is a moderator. That doesn't mean he gets to make the rules, it means the community trusts him to interpret the rules sensibly and take action unilaterally. That means mistakes can happen, as was the case here.

But the mistake was just deleting before closing. A procedural error. Robert was not wrong to close or delete the question.

Please understand that Robert has a far far better understanding of the site scope and rules than most other people. It is understandable that you are frustrated by his moderation actions. But that your comments here seem to claim that you know the site rules better than him is, quite frankly, insulting to the entire community.

---

Why was the question closed and deleted?

You are welcome to come to this community with software engineering questions.
But we expect that you abide by the rules of this community.
Among other things, this includes:

- that questions are clear, answerable, and reasonably scoped
- that questions show prior effort to solve the problem
- that the subject matter of the question is Software Engineering

I don't think it's useful to rehash the arguments from the comments as to how your question meets or doesn't meet these criteria, so I'll just point out that relevant community policies have been discussed in the following posts:

- [Why was my question closed as "Too Broad?"](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6490/)
- [Green fields, blue skies, and the white board - what is too broad?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6961)
- [Where to start?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6366)

If you want to get your question answered here, you will:

- do further research into possible solutions for securing inter-service communication
- edit your deleted question to explain the potential solution, and why it won't work for your context
- edit your question to also explain further constraints or goals rather than asking for the “best” solution
- flag your question for reopening

Comment: I finished analyzing the situation. As per my analysis, the mistake was in the Question Subject - it did not end with Question Mark, nor it could be interpreted as a question summary. I will fix this and avoid in future. Is there guideline for Question Subjects? (probably I missed it - sorry). However the actual question body remains intact - it is specific and self-contained.

Comment: @AntonPryamostanov While question titles frame the entire question, it is not necessary that the title is a question linguistically. Re “the actual question body remains intact” – \*sigh\*. I can't force you to improve your question. I can just point out that your perception that the question were “specific and self-contained” differs from the community's perception. Please edit your question to discuss at least one potential solution, e.g. whether a pre-shared secret could be used to secure the inter-service communication and/or why Spring Security is unacceptable.

Comment: Hi @amon, the community can learn from individuals, can't it? If community is immutable it does not develop itself. Anyway, I updated the Title and added some potential solutions (and reasons why they can't be used). Please undelete the question. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with you, the question is fine, although it could have used a bit more info which I asked for in the comment.

I think your mistake here is to assume that there is a court of law level of rigour in enforcing the rules, hearing complaints, making sure everything is fair and an appeals process.

This is just an online forum where people post stuff. There are some vague rules to try and keep the posts to a general topic and various people express their opinions through the various voting methods.

No-one is getting rich by moderating stack exchange sites, You throw your question in the bear pit and you hope someone knows an answer and is willing to give it to you for free.

If it's not answered for whatever reason, just ask somewhere else. Or wait a bit and ask again in a different fashion.

Comment: thanks buddy. Just it does not make sense to delete questions. This smells with totalitarism.

Comment: given that most questions are probably found via google and we dont pay for disk space, sure why not have all the questions and spam etc. its kinda like the #noestimates movement. we are trapped in a paradime where moderation is seen as required. But is it really?... i mean, deep down

Comment: as soon as Stackoverflow/Stackexchange wont spam up in google search results, I will agree with you. As long as it is not - in its current state your web site is harmful for the IT in general, thanks to meaningless practices you use, wrong upvoted answers, overall ignorance of public here (including moderators) - and high SEO on top of it. I am still waiting for my valid question to be undeleted. What is the escalation path here? It exists?

Comment: no. you have no recourse. life is not fair. your question will never be undeleted. everyone else has moved on. its just you and me arguing in the dark while google makes money selling ads and pirating stack exchange answers

Comment: I have no other option than expel myself from the web site. Reason: my continuous requests to re-open question are ignored despite the argumentation and with no counter-argumentation (except "no you" argumentation which is not acceptable).

Comment: well except the options i outlined earlier